# Angular Firestore - async pipe returns null data

Tags: angular, firebase

I am pulling data from a firestore database. If I use a straightforward promise, then the data is returned properly. However, I have an ngIf that will only display data which is defined and there are initially several console that result from this as the data is asynchronous.

If I send the promise to the async pipe, the data is always null.

Service - making the call and returning the promise - works

```
getUserInfo( userId ) {
    var docRef = this.afs.collection('users').doc(userId);
    return docRef.ref.get();
}
```

Component - will work to display data

```
this.UserService.getUserInfo( this.userData.uid ).then(response=> {
    this.userInfo = response.data();
```

Component - will return a promise but data shows as null using async

```
this.userInfo = this.UserService.getUserInfo( this.userData.uid );
```

View

```
{{userInfo | json}} - will work using first component method

{{userInfo | async}} - shows a null
```

Am I using the async correctly? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: could you show the ngIf and userinfo part of the template?

Comment: first of all `this.UserService.getUserInfo( this.userData.uid );` will return a response and what you actually need is response.data() so `{{userInfo | async}}` will not give you proper output you need. but still this doesn't explain null.

Comment: try if this works. `{{ (userInfo | async)?.data() }}`

Comment: Did you see any error in browser console?